# Angular application can't get data from CORS-enabled site behind Cloudfare

Tags: angular, http, proxy, header, cors

I have problem with accessing to CORS-enabled site from Angular. There is no problem to get JSON data from endpoint by browser, but it is impossile to get it from Angular. Always shows problem:

> access to XMLHttpRequest at '***' from origin 'http://localhost:4200'
> has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
> header is present on the requested resource.

This is my service:

```
export class GetService {
  private url = '***'
  headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getList(): Observable<List[]> {
    return this.http.get<List[]>(this.url + 'list/', { headers: this.headers });
  }
```

I tried already:

- put the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin to * as seen above (I also tried without headers)
- check other headers settting (Host, User-Agent, etc)
- [built-in proxy](https://www.positronx.io/handle-cors-in-angular-with-proxy-configuration/)

And still nothing. With built in proxy I get other erros:

> Please enable cookies.
> Error 1003
> Ray ID: *** • 2021-10-31 15:54:16 UTC
> Direct IP access not allowed
> What happened?
> You've requested an IP address that is part of the Cloudflare network. A valid Host header must be supplied to reach the desired website.
> What can I do?
> If you are interested in learning more about Cloudflare, please visit our website.
> Cloudflare Ray ID: *** • Your IP: *** • Performance & security by Cloudflare

I still can get the data by typing endpoint address to browser directly, so I assume, that I have to trick endpoint somehow, that the browser is connecting to it, not Angular app. What can I do?

Comment: what is ur backend ? spring boot or what  ?

Comment: I don't know - I just got endpoint adresses

Comment: always cors should be enabled from server side

Answer (score 0):

You do not set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' on the client (angular) you set it on the server.

If you have control over the server add this to your server.

If you do not have control over the server then create an [angular proxy configuration](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/angular-how-to-proxy-to-backend-server-6fb37ef0d025).

This proxy configuration will need to be repeated on all web server on all environments.

Comment: I made an angular proxy configuration, I tried the way with rewriting paths, and now it looks like this: {
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "https://www.***",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/api/list": "/product/list",
            "^/api/formats": "/product/formats",
            "^/api/papers": "/product/papers"
        }
    }
}, so when I get into localhost:4200/api/list it shows output from endpoint without any errors - as it should be. To be continued...

Comment: But the main problem is, when I want to get data by service, I have error "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.***/product/list' (redirected from 'http://localhost:4200/api/list/') from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: have u got, for example, a node.js backend express server running locally? if so what port is it running on on localhost? what URL are you making HTTP requests to? the idea behind the proxy is that you forward the requests to your backend server who can then make the request to anything since backend servers are not subject to CORS

Comment: to be honest i guess you could proxy to any domain and skip having your own BE server - what I really need to know to be able to help is ..... (1) what domain and port is your app running on? localhost:4200 I assume? (2) what URL are you making the HTTP request to?

Comment: I don't have access to the server. It is public domain like www.emp****oto.pl (i don't want 
to put full address here). So backend is not locally, and my frontend Angular app (with enabled proxy) is on localhost:4200. It is still intresting, why can I access to that endpoint by browser, but not from Angular service.

Comment: ok - within angular when you are using proxy config and you want to make request to ... www.emp****oto.pl ... you do NOT do this ... this.http.get('http://www.emp****oto.pl/url-path') ... instead you MUST do this ... this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/api/url-path') ... and if your proxy is configured correctly the Angular dev server will redirect the request ... this proxy setup will need to be repeated on production web servers also

Comment: note that if you don't have access to the server then this approach is your ONLY solution - note that this solution works because only browsers are restricted by CORS, hence why the Angular dev server can redirect the request without an issue - if you do this ...  this.http.get('emp****oto.pl/url-path') ... then the browser makes the request and it will get blocked by CORS

Comment: I have in my service: private url = '/api/'
  headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getList(): Observable<List[]> {
    return this.http.get<List[]>(this.url + 'list/', { headers: this.headers });
  }
  }, (headers are not important), that means that all the request is going to localhost:4200/api. And I can go from browser to localhost:4200/api and I see the JSON answer form server. But from Angular service there is still an error

Comment: ok your service code sounds right ... what does your proxy conf look like? what does the browser netowrk tab say about the request? is it failing with 404 or 500 or what? when you start angular dev server can u see that the proxy conf is being picked up?

Comment: so the proxy configuration is above, browser network tab says 200 when i open localhost:4200/api/list (API behind created proxy), the same when I get on www.emp***oto.pl/products/list (original location of API), and also 200 when I go on localhost:4200 (app is running, but then there are errors from service in console). The proxy is running, I can see the debug output from proxy. Strange problem, it shouldn't generate an error on app if I can open localhost:4200/api/list

Comment: since u r always getting 200 it seems your proxy conf is correct and this is an error with your code? whats the error the service is giving? what response is the API call giving within the service code?

Comment: Ok, so here is all the screenshots, which may clear out what is going on: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Air8sL47nxA3k5cVddFQwuubjFSpBg?e=ULMW6y - as you can see, I can access to api normally, and by proxy (localhost:4200/api/list == emp**oto.pl/product/list), and both of that request works in the browser. But both of them also fails in Angular service.